# Securing JQuery Ajax call to submit score via facebook Graph API

Tags: jquery, ajax, security, facebook-graph-api

I am using an ajax call to call a WCF service I have to post scores.  I see 3 basic options for securing it, but I'm not sure which is best (or perhaps a combination) or *exactly* how to do any of them.

1) Obscure/obfuscate the code.  Is this even possible?  A tangent of this is just hiding specific variables I don't want people to see.  I've read something about "closure" but I don't fully understand it.

2) Using some sort of hash.  As with above, can I even hide it?

3) Checks & Balances.  Basically constantly submit a score to my server on various events to keep track of the score.  Ban users who submit things outside of the defined possible parameters.  (ie, submitting a score over 100,000 when no previous scores have been "checked in" for that session.

I'm guessing a combination of 2 & 3 would be best.  Any links or tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) – won’t work, JS code beautifiers exist, and everyone can look at the data you’re sending anyway, in the firebug network tab for example.

Closures are a JS mechanism of encapsulating code in functions, so that no „outside” function can access it. Won’t make much difference though, because I can happily debug into your code and see what’s going on.

2) – won’t work, if you calculate the hash client side, I can a) see the algorithm and b) tamper with the data before you hash it.

3) might be you’re best option to get *some* security into it.

But if you want it „totally secure”, then you don’t want to use open client side technologies like JavaScript – maybe Flash would be a better alternative, although of course that’s not totally safe from reverse engineering as well. But it’d definitely set the bar some higher.

Comment: This was a long time ago but I think I got it pretty darn tamper-proof.  http://cosmati.net/biebsattack if you want to give it a go.  Keep in mind this was just an exercise lol :)

Answer (score 1):

You always SHOULD post scores from server side to not reveal your application `access_token` to visitors.

Citing [documentation for scores](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/score/):

> **Create or update a score for a user**
>   You can post a score or a user by issuing an HTTP POST request to `/USER_ID/scores` with the **app `access_token`** as long as you have the publish_actions permission.

**Update:**
As it seems that you trying to secure communication between client and your service, generally it is much safer to calculate the scores based on user's actions at server-side, that way you may concentrate on suspicious behavior rather than detecting fake scores submissions to secure your application.

Comment: I think he does, that why he uses AJAX to call his WCF service; but that’s not the problem – the client side calls to that service are: Anyone could (m|f)ake a call to that service, and thereby have it publish whatever scores they like …

Comment: I'm not currently posting scores server-side. But if I did have a WCF service that I called client-side to post scores server-side, won't I have the same problem?  The user would simply be able to inspect the DOM and see the network call to myService.wcf and all the values (username, score).